# /bootstrap/ directory doesn't exist. Where do I run `npm install`? (Part of bootstrap tutorial.)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm

I was following [this](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) bootstrap tutorial:

> **Installing Grunt**
>
> To install Grunt, you must first download and install
> node.js (which includes npm). npm stands for node packaged modules and
> is a way to manage development dependencies through node.js.
>
> Then, from the command line:
>
> 1. Install grunt-cli globally with npm
>    install -g grunt-cli.
> 2. **Navigate to the root /bootstrap/ directory, then
>    run npm install.** npm will look at the package.json file and
>    automatically install the necessary local dependencies listed there.
>
> When completed, you'll be able to run the various Grunt commands
> provided from the command line.

Regarding the part in bold:

> Navigate to the root /bootstrap/ directory, then run npm install

I can't navigate to /bootstrap/ directory.

```
$ cd /bootstrap/
-bash: cd: /bootstrap/: No such file or directory
```

I already installed node.js. I tried running `npm install` (with and without `sudo`) in the bootstrap-3.3.5-dist directory, and got this error:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /Users/myUsername/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/Users/myUsername/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/myUsername/Development/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/npm-debug.log
myUsernames-mbp:bootstrap-3.3.5-dist myUsername$
```

and here are the contents of the npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install' ]
2 info using npm@2.11.3
3 info using node@v0.12.7
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /Users/myUsername/.npmrc. (matches userconf$
5 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from /Users/myUsername/package.json
6 error install Couldn't read dependencies
7 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/myUsername/package.json'
7 verbose stack     at Error (native)
8 verbose cwd /Users/myUsername/Development/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist
9 error Darwin 13.4.0
10 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
11 error node v0.12.7
12 error npm  v2.11.3
13 error path /Users/myUsername/package.json
14 error code ENOPACKAGEJSON
15 error errno -2
16 error package.json ENOENT, open '/Users/myUsername/package.json'
16 error package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
16 error package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current direct$
17 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

**Where/how am I really supposed to run npm install? Why doesn't my /bootstrap/ directory exist?**

Comment: Create an empty directory and cd into it. Run `npm install bootstrap`, wait until download has finished. Now you should find a dir called *node_modules* inside your created dir. cd into that and you will find *bootstrap* dir. Inside *bootsrap* dir run `npm install`. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that by downloading the zip file, it wasn't creating the proper directory. So I tried installing from the command line (`npm install bootstrap`) and I noticed that the terminal had a message that the bootstrap directory was located at `../../bootstrap/` (or something like that). So I navigated to that directory, and then I was able to `run npm intall` which ran successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I think bootstrap's documentation makes this really unclear, but this section of the instructions isn't showing you how to install bootstrap, it is showing you how to set up your installation for if you want to compile custom variables or run test or fancy things like that. So this section of instructions requires you to have bootstrap installed first. That's why you are getting the error.  You can either download the zip file from bootstrap, use the CDN, or use "bower install bootstrap" or "npm install bootstrap" to actually get bootstrap running. You likely don't even need to do the steps in the part of the documentation you posted.

Comment: I had already downloaded the zip file and extracted to `/Users/myUsername/Development/`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Bootstrap 4:

Assuming you are running Windows 10 and that you have Ruby, Jekyll, Bundler and Node installed.

Step 1:
Point the browser to this address (which will download the zip file):
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v4.1.0.zip

Step 2:
Unzip to a location of choice. For example, to C:\Users\PC\Desktop\bootstrap-4.1.0

Step 3:
Navigate to the root of the unzipped folder (in my case, that was C:\Users\PC\Desktop\bootstrap-4.1.0\bootstrap-4.1.0).

Step 4:
Open git bash in the root mentioned in the previous step, and run `npm install`. This will take about 10 minutes and the console might seem like it's frozen. It's not, it is working, so please just be patient.

Alternatively, you can run:

```
npm install --loglevel verbose
```

This command will output a lot more information to the console so you can keep track of what is happening easier.

Step 5:
Once it's done, run: `bundle install`.

Step 6:
Next, run: `bundle exec jekyll build`.

Step 7:

```
cd _gh_pages
```

Step 8:

```
jekyll serve --watch
```

Step 9:
Open your browser at 127.0.0.1:4000 and view your local copy of the Bootstrap docs.